# Delegate.CreateDelegate() creates wrong delegate when multiple methods only differ in 1 enum parameter

Tags: c#, delegates

I have some issues creating the correct delegates for some methods of my classes. There is a base class and a derived class, both have a method `protected object GetValue (EnumPID)`, but `EnumPID` is defined separately in both classes. So in general both functions can be distinguished from each other.
Now I tried to create delegates to these functions using
`Delegate.CreateDelegate (Type, object, string)`,
because `new <delegate-name>(function)` does not work as the `function` is not public.
The failure is that both delegates created by `Delegate.CreateDelegate()` point to the same function, which is the one from the derived class.

To simplify it, here's the test class. I found out, that it's not necessary to use inheritance, it can be reproduced with 2 different enums in the same class as well:

```
public class CClass
{
  public delegate void DelegatePrint1 (Enum1 i_en1);
  public delegate void DelegatePrint2 (Enum2 i_en2);
  public delegate void DelegatePrint3 (Enum3 i_en3);

  public enum Enum1 { a = 1, b = 2 }
  public enum Enum2 { a = 99 }
  public enum Enum3 { z = 100 }

  public void Print (Enum1 i_en1) { Console.WriteLine (i_en1.ToString () + "=" + (int)i_en1); }
  public void Print (Enum2 i_en2) { Console.WriteLine (i_en2.ToString () + "=" + (int)i_en2); }
  public void Print (Enum3 i_en3) { Console.WriteLine (i_en3.ToString () + "=" + (int)i_en3); }
}

private static void Main ()
{
  string sMethod_Print = "Print";
  var oClass = new CClass ();
  var delPrint1 = (CClass.DelegatePrint1)Delegate.CreateDelegate (typeof (CClass.DelegatePrint1), oClass, sMethod_Print);
  var delPrint2 = (CClass.DelegatePrint2)Delegate.CreateDelegate (typeof (CClass.DelegatePrint2), oClass, sMethod_Print);
  var delPrint3 = (CClass.DelegatePrint3)Delegate.CreateDelegate (typeof (CClass.DelegatePrint3), oClass, sMethod_Print);
  delPrint1 (CClass.Enum1.a);
  delPrint1 (CClass.Enum1.b);
  delPrint2 (CClass.Enum2.a);
  delPrint3 (CClass.Enum3.z);
}
```

The expected output is

```
a=1
b=2
a=99
z=100
```

The actual output is

```
1=1
2=2
99=99
z=100
```

because all delegates call the `Print(Enum3)`.

My questions:
1) How can I create the *correct* delegate?  (I've already found out, see my own answer below).
2) Why does `CreateDelegate (Type, object, string)` create a delegate of the wrong function? Is the given Type not sufficient to determine the correct one?

Answer (score 1):

Obviously the constructor of a delegate is much smarter than the `Delegate.CreateDelegate()` function, because
`var del1 = new CClass.DelegatePrint1 (oClass.Print);`
creates the *correct* delegate, but this only works if the function is public.

The solution is: Instead of
`Delegate.CreateDelegate (Type, object, string)`
you must use
`Delegate.CreateDelegate (Type, object, MethodInfo)`
with the MethodInfo being
`var oMethod1 = typeof (CClass).GetMethod ("Print", new Type[] { typeof (CClass.Enum1) });`
In this way the correct overload of `Print` is selected.

As to why this is necessary (which is my 2nd question), I don't have an answer. I checked out the .net source of `CreateDelegate()` at https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/delegate.cs,2b489eed284b305b, but I am not quite sure about how it works, because it calls external methods `MulticastDelegate InternalAlloc(RuntimeType type)` and `bool BindToMethodName(Object target, RuntimeType methodType, String method, DelegateBindingFlags flags)`. I guess that either the type information is not fully preserved by `InternalAlloc`, or `BindToMethodName` takes the `Enum` as an `int`.